# Set a different error log file for a specific PHP file

Tags: php, debugging

I have several websites hosted on a Windows Server 2008 machine.

I'm logging errors to disk. There are a lot of them from various scripts and plugins that I have installed that I am not interested in.

Is there a way to set a different error log for the specific PHP file that I am working on, so that I can get *only* the errors I'm interested in while I do development?

I tried setting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_log", "c:\PHPLogs\special.log");
```

at the top of the file I wanted to debug, but no log file appears and I'm uncertain if this would even do what I want if it was working.

Comment: Try to manually create the files with the right chmod permissions (write access for the php user)

Comment: Good thought. I tried it and no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

In php.ini you need to set

fastcgi.logging = 1